# Unable to parse the data from string to html in javascript nodejs express

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, express

**My app.js file will send the data to EJS file.**

````
    app.get('/', function (req, res){
         Blog.find({}, function(err, fountItems){
           Blog.insertMany(defaultBlog, function(err){
           })  
        }
        res.render("home", {
          posts: fountItems   
        });
      })  
    });```
````

**home.ejs**

````
   <% posts.reverse().forEach(function(post){ %>
    <div id=log>
    </div>
        <script>
            var $log = $( "#log" ),
            str = "<=% post.content => ",
            html = $.parseHTML( str );
            $log.append( html );
        </script>
   <% }) %>```
````

if **post.content** is  `<h1>hello</h1>, <p>my name is</p> jQuery.` , then id should show without h1 and p tags. But output showing still with tags.
If i hardcode like  `str = "<h1>hello</h1>, <p>my name is</p> jQuery`  ", then its working fine. Through variable.

i'm unable to pass the value Am i missing anything. ref link
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Comment: `post.content` most probably is multiline... Try with backticks: `str = \`<=% post.content => \`,`

Answer (score 1):

By adding  **<%- post.content %>** worked.

```
    <% posts.reverse().forEach(function(post){ %>
        <div id=log>
        </div>
            <script>
                var $log = $( "#log" ),
                str = '<%- post.content %>,
                html = $.parseHTML( str );
                $log.append( html );
            </script>
           <% }) %>


     <% for (var i = 0 ; i < posts.length ;i++){ %>
                <div class="home-content">
                </div>
                    <script>
                        var $log = $( ".home-content" ),
                        str = `<%- posts[i].content %>`,
                        html = $.parseHTML( str );               
                        $log.appendTo(html)
                    </script>
      <%}%>
```

```
  posts = [
    {
        content: "Hello World 1"
    },
    {
        content: "Hello World 2"
    },
    {
        content: "Hello World 3"
    }
    ]
```

Output like below. Not sure why loop is behaving like this. is this something wrong with loop or jQuery append method.

```
   Hello World 1
   Hello World 2
   Hello World 3

   Hello World 2
   Hello World 3

   Hello World 3
```